# Nested lightning components with force ns not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am on Spring 17', When I use aura: iterate and wrap my lightning components inside a `<div>`, the inner component does not render.

**Critical Update locker service is enabled**

> **Working Scenario : OuterComponent / App:**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" access="global" controller="LtngCtrler">
    <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:iteration var="con" items="{!v.contacts}">            
        <c:innerCmp contact="{!con}" />
    </aura:iteration>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{!c.doSubmit}" />
</aura:application>
```

> **Working Scenario : InnerComponent :**

```
<aura:component access="Global">
    <aura:attribute access="global" name="contact" type="Contact" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact' }"/>
    <force:inputField aura:id="contactName" value="{!v.contact.Name}"/>
    <force:inputField aura:id="contactmobile" value="{!v.contact.MobilePhone}"/>
    <force:inputField aura:id="contactEmail" value="{!v.contact.Email}"/>
</aura:component>
```

> **Working Sample :**

[image: Working]

However, when I wrap the **" force:inputFields"** inside a **"div"** tag either in the outer component where I iterate or if I use it inside inner component, the lightning component does not render.

> **Issue : OuterComponent / App :**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" access="global" controller="LtngCtrler">
    <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:iteration var="con" items="{!v.contacts}">            
        <div id="{!con.Id}"> <!-- for identifying which contact i am dealing with -->
            <c:innerCmp contact="{!con}" />
        </div>
    </aura:iteration>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{!c.doSubmit}" />
</aura:application>
```

This did not render the component, hence I tried to pass the contact id as an attribute to the inner component where I can set the container id.

> **Modified container logic :**

```
<aura:iteration var="con" items="{!v.contacts}">            
     <c:innerCmp contact="{!con}" container="{!con.Id}" />
</aura:iteration>
```

> **Inner Component :**

```
<aura:attribute access="global" name="container" type="String" />
    <div id="{!v.container}">
        <force:inputField aura:id="contactName" value="{!v.contact.Name}"/>
        <force:inputField aura:id="contactmobile" value="{!v.contact.MobilePhone}"/>
        <force:inputField aura:id="contactEmail" value="{!v.contact.Email}"/>
    </div>
```

> **Nested Component not rendering :**

[image: Not rendering]

Has anyone come across this behaviour? I mean i am pretty sure i have nested components inside HTML components earlier and it seemed to work just fine. Any insights?

> **Update :**

Found something interesting, looks like force namespaces are causing this issue.

```
<aura:component access="Global">
    <aura:attribute access="global" name="contact" type="Contact" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact' }"/>
    <aura:attribute access="global" name="container" type="String" />
    <div id="{!v.container}">
        <force:inputField aura:id="contactName" value="{!v.contact.Name}"/>
        <force:inputField aura:id="contactmobile" value="{!v.contact.MobilePhone}"/>
        <force:inputField aura:id="contactEmail" value="{!v.contact.Email}"/> 

        <ui:inputText label="{!v.container}" class="field" value="{!v.contact.Name}" updateOn="click"/>

    </div>
</aura:component>
```

When I added a **ui:inputText** inside the inner component, the UI fields appear despite being wrapped inside a div or nested inside other components.

[image: Ui working]

Comment: There is no issue with the container id , even if i wrap the component inside a div without id, it still does not render.

Comment: Are these components working fine, if they are not nested? Just to make sure there is no syntax issue.

Comment: Yup working fine without the divs ..

Comment: btw, the doInit simply does an action callback to get contacts limit to 5.  And it sets the attribute v.contacts, nothing much happening other than that.

Comment: I can tell you that, definitely there are no issues with component nesting, as I have done the same recently. There must be some issue with your code somewhere.

Comment: I found something interesting, the issue is specific to force namespaces not  ui: or our custom HTML entries. could this be an issue? Check the update